How can I work with a subfolder in a remix route
I have create a remix project with this command: npx create-remix project1
I have create this folder: "project1/app/routes/customer/"
I have create these 2 files:
project1/app/routes/customer/index.tsx:
export default function DefaultPage() {
  return <h1>I am the default page</h1>;
}

project1/app/routes/customer/$id.tsx:
export default function IdPage() {
  return <h1>I am the ID page</h1>;
}

I am visiting my app with these urls:
"http://localhost:5173/customer/ " -> It works, I see the default page
"http://localhost:5173/customer/15" -> I see the default page too, instead of the ID page.

Probably want to use this Remix Flat Routes to achieve this.

Yes i know it works with flat routes but i want to understand why it does not work with folders.

The issue is related to how Remix handles file-based routing with folders.
In Remix's file-based routing system, when you create routes in folders, you need to make a slight modification to ensure dynamic routes work correctly. Here's what's happening and how to fix it:

When using folders, Remix expects the dynamic parameter route to be defined in a specific way
Your current structure with $id.tsx in the folder might not be getting recognized properly

Do the following to fix it:

Rename your $id.tsx file to include a dot before the parameter:
Change: project1/app/routes/customer/$id.tsx
To: project1/app/routes/customer/.$id.tsx

So your folder structure should look like this:
project1/app/routes/customer/
├── index.tsx
└── .$id.tsx

The reason for this:

The dot (.) prefix is required for nested dynamic routes when using folders
This helps Remix distinguish between different types of routes and properly handle the parameter matching

After making this change, visiting:

http://localhost:5173/customer/ will show the default page
http://localhost:5173/customer/15 will show the ID page

If you want to access the ID parameter in your component, you can use the useParams hook:
import { useParams } from "@remix-run/react";

export default function IdPage() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return <h1>I am the ID page with ID: {id}</h1>;
}

And yes, you're correct that this works differently with flat routes. In flat routing (when all files are in the root routes directory), you don't need the dot prefix. For example:
app/routes/
├── customer.tsx
└── customer.$id.tsx

This should work without the dot prefix. The dot prefix is specifically needed for folder-based routing.
EDIT I:
It seems there was a change in how nested routes are handled in Remix 2.0. You need to create a “route layout” file for folder-based routing in Remix 2.0+. Here's the correct structure:
project1/app/routes/customer/
├── _index.tsx      (for the index route)
├── $id.tsx         (for the dynamic route)
└── route.tsx       (layout file)

Rename your files:

Change index.tsx to _index.tsx
Keep $id.tsx as is
Create a new route.tsx file

Here's what each file should contain:
route.tsx:
import { Outlet } from "@remix-run/react";

export default function CustomerLayout() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Customer Layout</h1>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}

_index.tsx:
export default function DefaultPage() {
  return <h1>I am the default page</h1>;
}

$id.tsx:
import { useParams } from "@remix-run/react";

export default function IdPage() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return <h1>I am the ID page with ID: {id}</h1>;
}

Now when you visit:

http://localhost:5173/customer/ - You should see the default page
http://localhost:5173/customer/15 - You should see the ID page with the ID parameter

Changes made are:

Adding the route.tsx layout file which uses Outlet to render nested routes
Using _index.tsx instead of index.tsx for the index route
Keeping $id.tsx for the dynamic parameter route

This structure follows Remix 2.0's routing conventions. The previous routing system (with dots) was used in earlier versions of Remix.
EDIT II:
Move your routes directly into the app/routes folder like this:
project1/app/routes/
├── customer.tsx         (layout route)
├── customer._index.tsx  (index route)
└── customer.$id.tsx     (dynamic route)

This is what each file should contain:
customer.tsx:
import { Outlet } from "@remix-run/react";

export default function CustomerLayout() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}

customer._index.tsx:
export default function DefaultPage() {
  return <h1>I am the default page</h1>;
}

customer.$id.tsx:
import { useParams } from "@remix-run/react";

export default function IdPage() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return <h1>I am the ID page with ID: {id}</h1>;
}

If this still doesn't work, you should share your Remix version (from package.json) and any specific error messages in the console.
EDIT III:
For Remix 2.15.1 with folder routes, here’s how it should work:
First, create a folder for your customer routes. Your structure should be:
project1/app/routes/
└── customer/
    ├── route.tsx       (parent layout)
    ├── index.tsx      (index route)
    └── $id/
        └── route.tsx   (dynamic id route)

This is what each file should contain:
customer/route.tsx:
import { Outlet } from "@remix-run/react";

export default function CustomerLayout() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}

customer/index.tsx:
export default function DefaultPage() {
  return <h1>I am the default page</h1>;
}

customer/$id/route.tsx:
import { useParams } from "@remix-run/react";

export default function IdPage() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return <h1>I am the ID page with ID: {id}</h1>;
}

Differences from the previous setup are:

The dynamic parameter ($id) needs to be a folder with its own route.tsx
The index file stays as index.tsx (not _index.tsx)
Each route segment needs its own route.tsx file


It doesn't work: I have a 404 error when visiting http://localhost:5173/customer/15...

I've updated the previous answer to fix the 404 error issue.

Does not work too...

Check the new edit above. If it still doesn't work, let me know what Remix version you're using.

The edit2 will work but there are no folders. My remix version is 2.15.1

I just edited the answer to include folder routes

It does not work. Sorry I am giving up with remix
